# reading data from tia portal by using C# and s7.net library

Tags: c#

i am trying to make  custom scada using C# and plc, i am trying to read double word data (`MD10`) from plc but i am receiving wrong numbers like: `1112353`,
My code:

```
var result2 = Convert.ToDouble((uint)plc.Read("MD10"));
textBox4.Text = string.Format("{0}", result2.ToString());
```

For word data i am receiving right results, code for word data:

```
string address=("MW0");
object result1 = plc.Read(address);textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}", result1.ToString());
```

Any ideas to receive right data from double word in a textbox? thank you in advance.

I am receiving numbers like `11123112` but the right results are like `5.552`

Comment: can you provide a Minimal Reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, which data do you recibe before casting?

Comment: Why the (uint) ?

Comment: I think correct code would be `var result2 = (double) plc.Read("MD10");`

Comment: Yes, my casting was a disaster, i tried your casting and another one that i found in S7.net document about reading s7 Dword but I received the same wrong answer. To be more specific I am trying to read analog signal from plc after normalizing and scaling it(0-100).I used a datablock for my output and its datatype is a real. My code :

Comment: My code : var result2 = Convert.ToSingle(plc.Read("DB1.DBD2")); textBox4.Text = result2.ToString(); and second attempt : uint result2 = (uint)plc.Read("DB1.DBD2"); textBox4.Text = result2.ToString(); , The result was the same with another form: 1.118263*10^9 and 1118263578 instead of 83.6699 that I am receiving in tia portal, Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a casting completely wrong, in you example you are writing something like this:

```
var result2 = Convert.ToDouble((uint)plc.Read("MD10"));
textBox4.Text = string.Format("{0}", result2.ToString());
```

You want to have a double and you are expecting decimals: "the right results are like `5.552`" but you are casting to `uint`

i would definitely remove the casting and as siemens is using 4 bytes as a `double` i would suggest to convert to `single`, this will cast automatically to a `floating` data type (4 Bytes):

```
var result2 = Convert.ToSingle(plc.Read("MD10"));
```

After that you should have the correct values in the variable `result2`, converting this value to a string is trivial so after that you will have the correct data in your text box.

Comment: Yes, my casting was a disaster, i tried your casting and another one that i found in S7.net document about reading s7 Dword but I received the same wrong answer. To be more specific I am trying to read analog signal from plc after normalizing and scaling it(0-100).I used a datablock for my output and its datatype is a real. My code :

Comment: My code : var result2 = Convert.ToSingle(plc.Read("DB1.DBD2")); textBox4.Text = result2.ToString(); and second attempt : uint result2 = (uint)plc.Read("DB1.DBD2"); textBox4.Text = result2.ToString(); , The result was the same with another form: 1.118263*10^9 and 1118263578 instead of 83.6699 that I am receiving in tia portal, Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and tell me exactly what do you get from `plc.Read("DB1.DBD2")`?, i read the documentation and you should get an object but maybe we need to perform a bit shift and then the casting

Comment: 1087160016 this is the result for this code:object result2=plc.Read("DB1.DBD2");textBox4.Text = result2.ToString();

Comment: It is very difficult to analyze it like this, i think you need to provide more information like a screenshot form the tia portal side and how you assign the value to the variable, you can edit your question and i will continue analyzing your question

Comment: I think you posted the info as an answer and the moderators deleted it, you can edit your question and paste all the information there

Comment: i found the solution , it is needed a single precision floating point with single declaration instead of int, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: By the way , i am writing in stl some code , do you know if it is possible to make a substraction there until a specific condition? I want to substract a stable amount of litres from the whole volume of a tank until i reach the requested amount

Comment: it is a very general question, you can open a new topic, if you found a solution to your problem please post your answer, in that way people with the same question will see what you have done to achieve your goal